# Let f; g : D⟶$\mathbb R$ be two continuous functions. f(x) > 0 ∀x∈D. Prove that the function h : D⟶$\mathbb R$ by h(x) = $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity

I need to prove that : $\lim_{x\to x_0}\ f(x)^{g(x)} = f(x_0) ^{g(x_0)}$

This is what I did: $\lim_{x\to x_0} \ f(x)^{g(x)} =\lim_{x\to x_0} \ e^{ln({f(x)^{g(x)}})}= e^{ln({f(x_0)^{g(x_0)}})}= f(x_0) ^{g(x_0)}$

I really want to know if there is another way to solve this.
Thank you!

Comment: And why is $\lim_{x\to x_0} \ e^{ln({f(x)^{g(x)}})}= \lim_{x\to x_0} \ e^{ln({f(x_0)^{g(x_0)}})}$?

Comment: Right. I'll fix it.

Comment: "Another way" assumes having one way already, which your work is not, because it is circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We take limit on $\ln h(x) = g(x) \ln f(x)$ instead of $h(x)$.

1. By composition of continuous functions, $\ln \circ f$ is continuous on $D$.
2. The product of two continuous functions $g$ and $\ln \circ f$ are again continuous on $D$.
3. By composition of continuous functions, $\exp \circ (g \cdot \ln \circ f)$ is continuous on $D$.  Therefore,
   $$h(x) = \exp(\ln(h(x))) = \exp(g(x) \ln(f(x)))$$
   is continuous.